# ambari cluster + missing folders under /var/run/ambari-server

Tags: redhat, ambari

we have very strange problem

we installed new ambari cluster

but we notice that the folders - stack-recommendations and bootstrap on ambari server machine , are missing

stack-recommendations and bootstrap folders must be under /var/run/ambari-server

what could be the problem ?

```
cd /var/run/ambari-server/
[root@master02 ambari-server]# ls -ltr
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6 Feb 25 10:32 ambari-server.pid
```

from ambari-server log:

```
WARN [ambari-client-thread-217] StackAdvisorCommand:304 - Error occured during stack advisor command invocation:
java.io.IOException: Cannot create /var/run/ambari-server/stack-recommendations
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.stackadvisor.commands.StackAdvisorCommand.createRequestDirectory(StackAdvisorCommand.java:322)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.stackadvisor.commands.StackAdvisorCommand.invoke(StackAdvisorCommand.java:289)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.stackadvisor.StackAdvisorHelper.recommend(StackAdvisorHelper.java:113)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.RecommendationResourceProvider.createResources(RecommendationResourceProvider.java:92)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ClusterControllerImpl.createResources(ClusterControllerImpl.java:298)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.persistence.PersistenceManagerImpl.create(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:97)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.CreateHandler.persist(CreateHandler.java:37)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.BaseManagementHandler.handleRequest(BaseManagementHandler.java:73)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseRequest.process(BaseRequest.java:144)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:126)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:90)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.RecommendationService.getRecommendation(RecommendationService.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1507)
```

Comment: They don't exist because the error says they can't be created... Ambari agent / server is running under a limited user account, and can't create them maybe?

Comment: as @cricket_007 told, check permissions for `/var/run/ambari-server/`. Ambari process user should able to access that path with `rw ` permissions